# How to create a config page from which i can route to different activities in Android? Any sample source is great

Tags: android, config

I want to create an Android app which require one page from where i can launch different Activities like Config a timer, about page home page etc.... How to create a config page from which i can route to different activities in Android? Any sample source is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explain your problem more preciously.....
Make a page With Different Buttons.And for Each Button **setOnClickListener**.in Each OnClickListener in Onclick Event start newActiviy by making Object of Intent.
Like...

```
Button btListe = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_Liste);
    btListe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {   public void onClick(View v) 
        {   
            intent = new Intent(main.this, ListViewImage.class);
            startActivity(intent);      
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Help me to understand complexity of your problem.

Comment: Thanks Lunar. Actually i want one page with icons from where user can go to different activities. Actually same thing we can achieve via option menu, but i want to make it generic so that it can run on 3.0 and higher versions also. is there any best practice for that?

Comment: sorry for late response...you can use Dash-Board. and it is also supportable by lower as well as higher versions.Even more effective to so your app will have more richer look.[-->ActionBarSherlock<--](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: Thanks Lunar, i used Sherlock,